# Failing to get results using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, download, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve a file using `XMLHttpRequest` with Javascript. I'm having some problems getting the data of the sample file.

Here is the simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{           
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}

xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt", true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
</script>
```

With the above code I don't get any alerts. If I remove `&& xmlHttp.status == 200` then I get an empty alert, (I don't know why the server isn't giving the 200 status code). I tried different URLs but they all give out the same results.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Does the console shed any light on the issue?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.sitepoint.com/working-around-origin-policy/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy,

Comment: Are you running this script on domain http://humanstxt.org ?